# How can I make processing of matrices and vectors regular (as, e.g., in Matlab)

Tags: r, vector, matrix

Suppose I have a function that takes an argument x of dimension 1 or 2. I'd like to do something like

```
x[1, i]
```

regardless of whether I got a vector or a matrix (or a table of one variable, or two).

For example:

```
x = 1:5
x[1,2] # this won't work...
```

Of course I can check to see which class was given as an argument, or force the argument to be a matrix, but I'd rather not do that. In Matlab, for example, vectors *are* matrices with all but one dimension of size 1 (and can be treated as either row or column, etc.). This makes code nice and regular.

Also, does anyone have an idea why in R vectors (or in general one dimensional objects) aren't special cases of matrices (or multidimensional objects)?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand. If `x <- 1:5` what exactly do you think `x[1,2]` should return?

Comment: I think you will just need to use matrix types instead of vector types.  I'd be surprised if there was any other way.

Comment: Also, to answer your last question, it's because R is just as consistent, but in the other direction: matrices are special cases of vectors. It's just as convenient and consistent, just reversed, that's all.

Comment: Even if you do `x <- 1:5; x <- as.matrix(x)`, you will get a 5-by-1 matrix. As @joran noted, `x[1,2]` refers to a non-existent element. Were you maybe getting the row/column indices reversed?

Comment: I see. So, am I the only one who thinks it is a little awkward that matrices are vectors? (rather than that vectors are matrices)

Comment: vectors as special case of matrix might be more consistent mathematically but matrix as vector with dimensional attribute is more consistent with the machine representation of data and is in the tradition of other languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, it is the other way round; *matrices are vectors*. The matrix-like behaviour comes from some extra attributes on top of the atomic vector part of the object.

To get the behaviour you want, you'd need to make the vector be a matrix, by setting dimensions on the vector using `dim()` or explicit coercion.

```
> vm <- 1:5
> dim(vm) <- c(1,5)
> vm
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
> class(vm)
[1] "matrix"
```

Next you'll need to maintain the dimensions when subsetting; by default R will drop empty dimensions, which in the case of `vm` above is the row dimension. You do that using `drop = FALSE` in the call to `'['()`. The behaviour by default is `drop = TRUE`:

```
> vm[, 2:4]
[1] 2 3 4
> vm[, 2:4, drop = FALSE]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
```

You could add a class to your matrices and write methods for `[` for that class where the argument `drop` is set to `FALSE` by default

```
class(vm) <- c("foo", class(vm))
`[.foo` <- function(x, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) {
  clx <- class(x)
  class(x) <- clx[clx != "foo"]
  x[i, j, ..., drop = drop]
}
```

which in use gives:

```
> vm[, 2:4]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
```

i.e. maintains the empty dimension.

Making this fool-proof and pervasive will require a lot more effort but the above will get you started.

Comment: @GavinSmpson . Thanks for this explanation. But can you show me please  where the `[.vector` or `[.matrice` are defined in R. I can't find them in R sources.

Comment: In the C code. Read `?Extract` for the details. `'['()` is a Primitive in R parlance and hence dispatch for atomic vectors (note the vector in the OP's example is not of class `"vector"`, it will be a numeric or possibly integer vector) and matrices are handled internally via compiled C code.